# Extracting specific JSON object and pushing to new object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hey guys I have an obj that looks a bit like this.

```
[
    {
        "app": 1,
        "scalable": true,
        "zoomable": true,
        "cropBoxResizable": true
    },
    {
        "app": 2,
        "scalable": false,
        "zoomable": true,
        "cropBoxResizable": false
    }
]
```

What I'm trying to is basically extract which ever specific app related object data and save to a second obj. So for example if app = 1 then newObj will be something like this

```
var newObj = {
        "app": 1,
        "scalable": true,
        "zoomable": true,
        "cropBoxResizable": true
    }
```

Is there a way I can make this json format better? I'm open to that too. I'm just trying to figure out the most optimized way to approach this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried a loop? And an if statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over your array and check `app` to equality

```
var arr = [ { "app": 1, "scalable": true, "zoomable": true, "cropBoxResizable": true }, { "app": 2, "scalable": false, "zoomable": true, "cropBoxResizable": false } ]

function extract(a, app) {
    var length = a.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (a[i].app === app) {
            return a[i];
        }
    }
}

var newObj = extract(arr, 2)
console.log(newObj);
```

Result:

```
{ app: 2,
  scalable: false,
  zoomable: true,
  cropBoxResizable: false }
```

Comment: This is perfect, Thank you so much..so much better than what I had! TIL :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code , this is the simplest way

```
var source = [
    {
        "app": 1,
        "scalable": true,
        "zoomable": true,
        "cropBoxResizable": true
    },
    {
        "app": 2,
        "scalable": false,
        "zoomable": true,
        "cropBoxResizable": false
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (source[i].app == "1") {
         console.log(source[i]);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well should be much better to use object as a container instead of array.

```
const src = { "1": // this is app name
  {
    "scalable": true,
    "zoomable": true,
    "cropBoxResizable": true
  },
  "2":
  {
    "scalable": false,
    "zoomable": true,
    "cropBoxResizable": false
  }      
};
```

so then just 
const appData = src['1'];